# Umbraco XSLT Performance factors 

Tags: performance, xslt, razor, umbraco

In Umbraco CMS. Is there a way to test and see how longs it takes to pull nodes of a certain DocType in XSLT?  Is there an XSLT timer or anything that can do this.

We are trying to test what is faster to use. Razor or XSLT for our needs.  In Razor we can get the time because it is essentially C# but if XSLT is rendered faster, we would like to use that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you append a querystring of `?umbdebugshowtrace=true` to your page you will get a stack trace of the various processes on your page - so you will be able to see when your xslt processes.

[image]

You could also use [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809618/umbraco-cms-net-logging-errors-loading-xslt-user-controls) to write into your umbracolog and use that as a rough timer (obviously some lag in the write).

Comment: Thank you amelvin. I wan unaware the StackTrace gave me that information.  Much appreciated and good info in the future.

Comment: amelvin, So we are testing 2 different ways of getting nodes with a specific property. We query the whole tree (over 2000 nodes) and pull those nodes with the property.  In XSLT it loads much quicker and does not cause lag on the website. But when we use Razor the website lags and the CPU spikes at 100%.  Is there something XSLT is doing differently than Razor.  Is it using the XML file and is Razor using the Database or something. We are confused what the issue might be?

Comment: @Carlos when umbraco runs it uses the umbraco.config file in the App_Data folder, this file is in XML format.  It makes sense that in some circumstances a well formed xslt query will process a big umbraco.config file quicker than a razor query.

Answer (score 3):

Well In my opinion **"XSLT is rendered faster"** is pretty relative thing. In-fact if you consider 1 Million record to be render on umbraco page there is only marginal differance in page load when you test with XSLT and Razor.

A side note..... which is good for you to select between two; It is not the speed issue that makes you to choose between two but there are following things to consider.

1. XSLT were famous when there was no RAZOR.
2. Razor are easy (much easier) to work with compare to XSLT.
3. Razor are generic and asp.net MVC developer can adopt umbraco development with RAZOR.
4. RAZOR is future.
5. Razor are much more readable and maintainable compare to XSLT.

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104361/is-razor-or-xslt-better-for-my-project as well.

My Vote.. If you are starting a new project please spend some learning curve with RAZOR and you will gain a lot in long run.

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: the question is how to measure the speed of xslt - the OP states he wants to make a straight choice based on speed

Comment: amelvin is absolutely correct. I need to know speed performance. I know Razor is the future, it is more generic, etc., etc.  But somethings in the rendering of Macros XSLT seems to be faster and in some other cases Razor would be faster.   That is why I would like to know how to measure time.